# 3D model filled with cubes of fixed size

Tags: python, mesh, bounding-box, vertices, wavefront

[image: Simple 3D model of Humanoid]

I have geometry definition in .obj file /WaveFront format/**.** I can load meshes of this 3D model and get vertices **:**

> [[ 0. 0. 0.] ,[ 0. 0. 3.25] ,[-2.48 14. 0.]   ,[ 0.  0.  0.] ,[0. 3.25
>   -2.48] ,[9.01 0. 0.] ,...]

QUESTIONS -- what i have accomplish **:**

- How fill the model with the same cubes of the given size /in mathematical sense/ using Python 2.7 ?
- In advanced mode I have each squares have random|different color and draw by using pyOpenGL ?

Comment: That's all very nice, but what is your question is?

Comment: I re-formatted code. So you can go with your answer. OK.